# djang oscar voucher and offers

Tags: django, python-3.x, e-commerce, django-oscar

if i have a single offer that gives 10% off 
and also i have a voucher that give 10% off in same products.

when i add these two offers to my basket, voucher discount not applied.
if i change the priority of offers i can add voucher but single offer discount not applied.

**i need to apply these two offers to the basket.**

i created a custom condition for voucher offers. then i tried to consume 0 quantity to that offer.
but it's not working as i expected

```
class CustomCouponCondition(CountCondition):

    '''
        oscar_customize.offer.models.CustomCouponCondition
    '''

    name = "Custom Coupon Conditions"

    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def consume_items(self, offer, basket, affected_lines):

        for __, line in self.get_applicable_lines(offer, basket, most_expensive_first=True):
            line.consume(0, offer=offer)
```

Comment: You've not given enough code for me to fully understand the logic. From what I understand you are applying the offer to each line in the basket, and if thats the case can you not check if both offers are applicable and if so combine the discount percentage and apply it.

Comment: is there has another solution ?

Comment: I don't have much experience with django-oscar, so the best thing to do is to post this question again with better clarity and info so that others can answer.